# Length of Astroid tangent line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given the astroid $\gamma(t)=\langle\cos^3(t),\sin^3(t)\rangle$ for $t\in[0,2\pi]$, I'm trying to show that at any point, the tangent line to $\gamma$ that intersects the $x$-axis, and $y$-axis has length 1. I've found the equation of the tangent line to be $\sin(t)\cos(t)=x\sin(t)+y\cos(t)$, but now I'm unsure of where to go. My idea is to find the tangent at an arbitrary point $t_0$, find where it intersects the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, and show the length of this segment is 1. I'm having trouble actually doing this though. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form your equation: $\sin(t)\cos(t)=x\sin(t)+y\cos(t)$ you see that the intercept withe the coordinate axis are :
$$
y=0 \rightarrow x=\cos t \qquad x=0 \rightarrow y=\sin t
$$
so, $\forall t$ we have $x^2+y^2=\cos^2 t +\sin^2 t=1$

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line intersects $x-$ axis at point $A_t=(\cos t , 0)$ and $y-$ axis at $B_t =(0, \sin t)$ so $$|A_t B_t | =\sqrt{ (\cos t -0)^2 +(0-\sin t )^2} =1$$