# Equations in the form x(t)=cos^n(t),y(t)=sin^n(t); Circle is to Square is to Astroid is to Parabola is to...

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[Desmos Demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nucnphwozx)

I'm wordering about parametric equations in the form $(x,y)(t)=(\cos^n(t),\sin^n(t))$ for $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for various $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

$(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is a (quarter of a) circle. For points on the curve, the Euclidian distance to the origin is $1$. This is obvious since $\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$.

$(\cos^2(t),\sin^2(t))$ is a (quarter of a) square.  For points on the curve, the Manhattan distance to the origin is $1$. Again, this is obivious since $|\sin^2(t)|+|\cos^2(t)|=\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$.

$(\cos^3(t),\sin^3(t))$ is a (quarter of an) astroid. For lines tangent to the curve, the Euclidian distance between the $x$ and $y$ intercepts is $1$.  [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671930/length-of-astroid-tangent-line).

$(\cos^4(t),\sin^4(t))$ is (part of) a parabola. For lines tangent to the curve, the Manhattan distance between the $x$ and $y$ intercepts is $1$.  The proof of this is along the same lines as $n=3$ case.

What is $(\cos^5(t),\sin^5(t))$, or the curve for any $n>5$? The $n=5$ curve looks pretty close to a hyperbola (but isn't one).  Is it just a coincidence that the Euclidian vs Manhattan distance properties I found arise in pairs? Or can something similar be said for $n=5$ and $6$?

Comment: You have, for $x,y \geq 0,$ $x^r + y^r = 1.$ For you $r \leq 2.$  For $r > 2$ you get squarish things.

Comment: @WillJagy yes, in particular I have $r=\frac{2}{n}$

Comment: See [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).